# upgrading to gpu in tensorflow with anaconda gives error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, anaconda, upgrade

I used the technique described in the answer to How to install Tensorflow on Windows 10 with anaconda?  That worked for me.  I then tried to run an upgrade to GPU with the following msg

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl

tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an error in the Windows installation instructions, which refers to a non-existent URL. You can enter one of the following commands instead:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```